# In PIE are words for two and for hate connected?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, numerals

In PIE we have

***du̯is*** twice

***du̯iteros*** second

***du̯oi̯os*** twofold

***du̯eiplos*** double

etc, with the root du̯ei̯-

At the same time we have:

***du̯eiros*** fearful

***du̯eisos*** hated

with seemingly the same root.

Is there any etymological or semantic connection?

P.S. After making this post I found that de Vaan postulates the following:
*dus 'into two > bad'

Comment: Very interesting question. What would the **concept** be for such a connection? What are the possibilities that this is a coincidence?

Comment: It's hard to evaluate these PIE reconstructions, or determine whether the same root is involved in all of them, without seeing the actual comparative data from the attested languages in each case. Scholars differ in their reconstructions, and probably not everyone would agree that all of the PIE forms you list really existed, so you might get better answers if you gave the evidence for each form.

Comment: @Midas there are known parallels: the dis- prefix which means "wrong". Compare disfunction, disorder, disorientation while it originated from the same root for 2.

Answer (score 2):

This connection is possible, perhaps even plausible, as long as you remember that Proto-Indo-European is not a real language but a theoretical construct. Everything about it is conjecture.

Answer (score 1):

Thing is, the PIE prefix meaning "bad" was `*dus-` from the root `*dwe-`, just as "two" was `*dwṓh1` from the root `*dwo-`. Their similarity is probably just coincidental.

I cannot find any explanation for the form `*dweysos` as that doesn't fit the participle pattern (`*-ónts *-ntés *-óntih2 *-ntyéh2s *-mh1nós`) nor for `*dweyros` as it doesn't fit an adjective derivation pattern (`*-yos *-iskos` etc.) Check your sources, please, then tell me: there might be something I'm missing here.

Comment: Root du̯e? What made you think such root could exist? Vowels are prohibited at root end in PIE.

Comment: At the very least, the roots `dwo-` (two), `kwṓ-` (dog), `dra-` (to run), `ghowro-` (fear), `solwo-` (entire), `médhu` (honey, mead) and `nogwó-` (nude) end in a vowel; `dwe-` is just as likely as they are to exist.

Comment: There's no root kwṓ-, there is cu̯en- (cu̯ōn "dog"). The root dra- is twice impossible because PIE had no a. (so the root could be dreh2-), ghou̯ros has the ending -os (and r is suffix, adjectives in -ros are common), solu̯os has the ending -os and u̯ is suffix (adjectives in -u̯os are also common), u in médhu is resonant (counted as consonant in PIE when considering the root structure), and most likely the root was medh- because the resonant could not be further from the kernel vowel than dh, with -u- as suffix, -os in neğnos is ending (and -n- is suffix).

Comment: I don't know to what theory you subscribe, but Indo-European as known today is realised to have had /*a/. I believe only Beekes (and by extension Lubotsky) is expressly against its inclusion. The vowel in `*dra-` is short, therefore there can't have been a laryngeal after it; `ḱwṓ-` (what is that /c/?) was a hysterokinetic noun - it's reflected without that final /n/ you cite in Hittite, Celtic, Tocharian and Slavic. Even if you exclude all those other roots (validly or not), you're still left with `*dwo-` and `*ḱwṓ-`

Comment: give an example of a word with dra-; "it's reflected without that final /n/ you cite in Hittite, Celtic, Tocharian and Slavic" - about what Slavic words do you speak? There is a word kunitsa "marten" in Russian, what other Slavic reflexes of this root? Anyway it is irrelevant, even if the final -n tended to be dropped in later times, it was a part of the root etymologically. It seems you only left with hypothetical du̯o-

Comment: "The vowel in *dra- is short" Are you sure the reflex you are speaking about does not reflect the zero grade? In zero grade the laryngeal will give you short -a-.

Comment: 1) `*dra-` gave "drāti" (Sanskrit), "draonah" (Avestan), apparently "drómos" (Greek) and "drebėti" (Lithuanian). Its lack of broken tone and a reflex other than /i/ in Sanskrit indicates there's no laryngeal as Sanskrit reflects all zero-grade laryngeal nuclei as /i/.

<br/>2) `*ḱwō-` is reflected as `*suka` in Slavic as per Satemisation. Its Celtic reflex is `*kū-` and Hittite `kuwas`. The /n/ has not been dropped as it's been maintained in the oblique stem (kuwas/kuwanan, kū/kunos, even Sanskrit śvā/śunas)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14267/discussion-between-darkgamma-and-anixx)

Comment: @Anixx, Darkgamma has already mentioned that it's mostly the representatives of Leiden U (Kortlandt, Beekes, Lubotsky) who are against the inclusion of *a* in PIE.

Comment: @Alex B. well if a is included then there is really no reason for laryngeals at all. Everything can be explained with long or short a.

Comment: @Anixx, it doesn't have to be either/or; there are some occurences of /a/ that just can't be explained with a laryngeal